# How should I find the x_value corresponding to the max or min y_value of a parabola? (in Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I've been tying to use `np.where` to find the `x` value that corresponds to the maximum `y` value of a parabola, here is what I did :

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(-10,10,step=1)
y = x**2+2*x
x = np.where(y=max)
print(x)
```

This clearly doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use argmin

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(-10,10,step=1)
y = x**2+2*x
idx = np.argmin(y)
print(x[idx])
```